# Odd behaviour of SlidingWindows when used with TestPipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, sliding-window

I've got a simple test that demonstrate an odd behaviour of sliding window when used with TestPipeline. Basically a bunch of strings is fed to the input, then they get accumulated in the sliding window, then the sum aggregation is applied to count the duplicates and finally the output of the aggregation function is logged. With a sliding window of 10 minutes duration and 5 minutes period I expected only one window being used to store all the elements (as the new one is started in 5 minutes after the first one)...

```java
public class SlidingWindowTest {
    private static PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SlidingWindowTest.class);

    private static class IdentityDoFn extends DoFn<KV<String, Integer>, KV<String, Integer>>
        implements DoFn.RequiresWindowAccess{
        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext processContext) throws Exception {
            KV<String, Integer> item = processContext.element();
            LOG.info("~~~~~~~~~~> {} => {}", item.getKey(), item.getValue());
            LOG.info("~~~~~~~~~~~ {}", processContext.window());
            processContext.output(item);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void whatsWrongWithSlidingWindow() {
        Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create(options);

        p.apply(Create.of("cab", "abc", "a1b2c3", "abc", "a1b2c3"))
            .apply(MapElements.via((String item) -> KV.of(item, 1))
                       .withOutputType(new TypeDescriptor<KV<String, Integer>>() {}))
            .apply(Window.<KV<String, Integer>>into(SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(10))
                                                        .every(Duration.standardMinutes(5))))
            .apply(Sum.integersPerKey())
            .apply(ParDo.of(new IdentityDoFn()));

        p.run();
    }
}
```

But I got **8** windows being fired instead. Is there something wrong with TestPipeline or with my understanding of how sliding windows are supposed to work?

```
12:19:04.566 [main] DEBUG c.g.c.d.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry - Default coder for com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.KV<java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer>: KvCoder(StringUtf8Coder, VarIntCoder)
12:19:04.566 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~> abc => 2
12:19:04.567 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~~ [-290308-12-21T19:50:00.000Z..-290308-12-21T20:00:00.000Z)
12:19:04.567 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~> abc => 2
12:19:04.567 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~~ [-290308-12-21T19:55:00.000Z..-290308-12-21T20:05:00.000Z)
12:19:04.567 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~> a1b2c3 => 2
12:19:04.567 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~~ [-290308-12-21T20:00:00.000Z..-290308-12-21T20:10:00.000Z)
12:19:04.567 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~> cab => 1
12:19:04.568 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~~ [-290308-12-21T19:50:00.000Z..-290308-12-21T20:00:00.000Z)
12:19:04.568 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~> a1b2c3 => 2
12:19:04.568 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~~ [-290308-12-21T19:50:00.000Z..-290308-12-21T20:00:00.000Z)
12:19:04.568 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~> cab => 1
12:19:04.568 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~~ [-290308-12-21T19:55:00.000Z..-290308-12-21T20:05:00.000Z)
12:19:04.568 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~> abc => 2
12:19:04.568 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~~ [-290308-12-21T20:00:00.000Z..-290308-12-21T20:10:00.000Z)
12:19:04.568 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~> cab => 1
12:19:04.568 [main] INFO  c.q.m.core.SlidingWindowTest - ~~~~~~~~~~~ [-290308-12-21T20:00:00.000Z..-290308-12-21T20:10:00.000Z)
```

P/S: Dataflow sdk version: 1.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected behavior is different that what you observe, but also different from what you expect:

- First, you have three different keys, so if they all fell into a single window, then you would expect three outputs.
- For sliding windows of 10 minutes with a 5 minute period, every element necessarily falls into two windows. If an element arrives at minute `1` it falls into both the window from `0` to `10` but also the window from `-5` to `5`. So you should expect **six** output values, two per key. It is a common pitfall to think of windows as something that updates as a pipeline runs, when in fact they are simply calculated properties of the input *data*, not a property of its arrival time or the pipeline's execution.
- The `Create` transform will output all values with a timestamp of `BoundedWindow.TIMESTAMP_MIN_VALUE` so they should all fall into the same two windows.

Your example seems to indicate a real bug. It should not be possible for `"a1b2c3"` to be in the two disjoint windows that it falls in, nor for `"abc"` to fall into three windows, two of which are disjoint.

Incidentally, though, you would benefit from checking out [`DataflowAssert`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/testing/DataflowAssert.java) (called [`PAssert`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/testing/PAssert.java) now in Beam) for testing the contents of a `PCollection` in a consistent and cross-runner way.

Comment: Thanks Kenn, that's a great answer! I'm using DataflowAssert already, in fact that's how I found out this odd behaviour with sliding window. Where do you think I better write a bug report to: dataflow or beam?

Comment: Since you are using the Dataflow SDK 1.8.0, I think you should report it against https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK, to emphasize that it has impact there. We will then most likely copy it to a Beam JIRA, fix it in Beam, and then backport. But we take these on a case-by-case basis.